# Python: Set object property from a string name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a class that can be initialized with a dictionary, attributing each entry in this dictionary to itself. I wrote the following which I expected to just work:

```
class dat:
    def __init__(self, data: dict):
        for d in data:
            self[d] = data[d]
```

But that produces the error:

```
TypeError: 'dat' object does not support item assignment
```

How do I set a property on `self` by its name? Internally I'd do something like `self.prop = 0` since I know what `prop` is called, but since this is a dictionary `prop` can be anything: Only way I know to set those is as `self[prop]` but if that doesn't work on objects I presume there's some builtin syntax or function of the form `self.set(prop)`?

Comment: `setattr(self, d, data[d])`

Comment: That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @enzo in the comment: `setattr(self, d, data[d])` does exactly what I want. Will likely be switching to `kwargs` as well which is better in combination with this approach.

Comment: While this does indeed work, I don’t quite understand why you would want to. There are some serious pitfalls with using setattr. For example, it means you can overwrite methods on the instance. If you want dict-like functionality, why not just use a dict?